# Gödel didn’t prove the incompleteness?

Tags: logic, proof, first-order-logic

Gödel’s proof considers an arbitrary system K containing natural number. The proof defines a relation Q(x,y) then considers ∀x(Q(x,p)) where p is a particular natural number. The proof shows that the hypothesis that ∀x(Q(x,p)) is K provable leads to contradiction, so ∀x(Q(x,p)) is not K provable. The proof proves then ∀n(├ Q(n,p)) that means Q(n,p) is K provable for all natural number n. The proof introduces a new ω-consistent claiming that for any property B(x), it’s not the case ∀n(├ B(n)) ⋀ (├ ¬∀x(B(x))), and assumes that K is ω-consistent. The proof proves that ¬∀x(Q(x,p)) is not K provable by that the assumption that it’s K provable, that is, ├ ¬∀x(Q(x,p)), is in contradiction with the assumption that K is ω-consistent as we have already ∀n(├ Q(n,p)). But the proof neglects the link between truth value and proof. Considering the propositional logic theorem B → B, the assumption of ∀x(Q(x,p)) in K would prove ∀x(Q(x,p)) in K then leads to contradiction, so we have ¬∀x(Q(x,p)), and ∀x(Q(x,p)) is not K provable as K is consistent, and then ∀n(├ Q(n,p)). In another side, the assumption of ¬∀x(Q(x,p)) in K would prove it in K and then lead to contradiction with the assumption that K is ω-consistent, so we have ∀x(Q(x,p)). Then, we have that either ∀x(Q(x,p)) is a paradox or K is not ω-consistent. But in both cases the proof doesn’t prove the incompleteness.

With this proof can we continue to consider that the incompleteness is proven?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I know hat there is a site for easy problem and there is a site for difficult problem. But I'm sorry for that I'm not sure which is for what. I believe that stackoverflow is for difficult problem, and that's why I raise the problem here.

Comment: If I'm wrong, I accept voluntarily to close this question and to raise it in the other site. I had raised the question of how to prove ¬(5|7), meaning 7 is not divisible by 5. I was told that the question is too easy so should be raised in the other site. But when I raised the qustion there, I was told that they are not able to answer the question. Then, the question remains always not answed.

Comment: So, please don't close a question because it's considered too easy. Easy problem should have an easy answer. So please don't feel bothered to answer it. To indicate an error in the question is also an answer to the question.

Comment: I didn't vote to close the question because of its difficulty, but because it's off-topic on this site (stackoverflow.com). Try asking it instead on either https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://mathoverflow.net/.

Comment: OK, the two sites are not this site but two other sites. I'll raise the problem there. Thanks.